# ASP.net MVC and jQueryUI dilemma

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, path, jquery-ui-theme

I just moved a project to the the beta release of `ASP.net MVC` framework and the only problem I am having is with `jQuery` and `jQueryUI`.

Here's the deal:

In `Site.Master` are the following script references:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And using those, the `accordian UI` that I have on one of the views works perfectly, except for one problem: the images from `ThemeRoller` aren't included on the page. If I comment out the jQuery references, the ThemeRoller images are there. All of the css is in the `Content folder` and all of the scripts are in the `Scripts folder`.

I know this is a silly path problem, but it's making me twitch.

What am I missing?

**Update**

I tried the first answer to no avail, read the comment for details. Thanks again for those who are viewing.

The second approach is not working either. I'm baffled.

**Another Update**

Using the `Url.Content` tags for the scripts does indeed allow the scripts to run properly. Using a regular tag for the stylesheet gets all of the styles onto the page EXCEPT for all of those related to ThemeRoller.

The `jquery-ui-themeroller.css` file is in the Content folder and when I inspect an element, the css is present. I suspect the problem is in the mapping from this css file to the images folder for the themeroller, which is in the Content folder as well. Image links in this file as specified as: `background: url(images/foo.gif)`

Do the links in this file need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this help?

http://forums.asp.net/p/1334947/2690469.aspx

> The reason for the inconstistency is
>   very simple, though I admit it's not
>   easy to figure out! When you have a
>   <link> tag inside a <head
>   runat="server">, ASP.NET will process
>   the <link> tag and detect URLs and
>   resolve them relative to the
>   application's root. When you have a
>   <script> tag on the page (without
>   runat="server") then ASP.NET will
>   leave it alone since it's just plain
>   old HTML.
>
> Using Url.Content() is the approach I
>   would use to solve this since it'll
>   get resolved relative to the app root,
>   just like the <link> tag.

Comment: It helped me understand the problem better and get closer, but the solution is still just out of my grasp.

Comment: Turns out the problem was that the downloaded theme from ThemeRoller doesn't work out of the box. Thanks for the pointer to the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Unless all your views are at the same level, you'll need to either use

- Use an absolute path such as /Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js
- Or even better, Resolve a virtual path such as <%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js") %>

[Url.Content() http://jvance.com/media/2008/10/18/UrlContent5.media](http://jvance.com/media/2008/10/18/UrlContent5.media)

Comment: I tried the option of using the Url.Content tag, which changed one thing:

Now with everything uncommented, the images display but the jQueryUI isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the links in jquery-ui-themeroller.css to point to the current location of the images.

As in, you need to update the path of the images that the css file is looking for.

```
background: url(images/foo.gif)
```

Remove the 'images/' from your paths to make it look  like:

```
background: url(foo.gif)
```

as both your css and images are in the content folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(),"JQuery", ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery.min.js"));
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), "JQueryUI", ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"));
```